# php mysql Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I don't know what's the wrong on my code I tryed this function on other file and that's worked but when i added it to a class and trying to call the function from other script file i get this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

my code

```
public function DisplayP(){
    <?php
    include('C:\xampp\htdocs\x\chessMult\connectToDB.php');

    //session_start();
    //include('C:\xampp\htdocs\x\chessMult\connectToDB.php');
    //include('C:\xampp\htdocs\x\chessMult\chMult\classes\user.php');

    $result = $_db->prepare("SELECT MatchP FROM users ORDER BY UserName DESC");
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();
    ?>

    <td><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\x3\editform.php"> edit </a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MatchP']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['UserName']; ?></td>

}
```

and when I remove

```
<td><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\x3\editform.php"> edit </a></td>
```

Comment: you're already in php, so why the php tags in there?

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i remove them iget the same error on this line   <td><?php echo $row['MatchP']; ?></td>